# Need a driver for OKI MC160n printer

Tags: drivers, printing

I can't find a driver for my OKI MC160n printer. How can I use this printer in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

## Driver for OKI MC160n Printer

Almost 3 years too late, but a big thanks to Squelsh for the tip! My MC160N has been gathering dust for years, but now works. Thank's to Squelsh's tip!

The link was dead but I found this [link](http://foo2lava.rkkda.com) and followed their instructions.

What I did IIRC:

- Download the tar and compile the driver

  ```
  $ wget -O foo2zjs.tar.gz http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz
  $ tar xvf foo2zjs.tar.gz
  $ cd foo2zjs
  $ make
  ./getweb 1690# Get Konica Minolta magicolor 1690MF .ICM files (***NOTE Didn't find any, ignored)
  ```
- Now you can install the **ppd**s (postscript printer describtions)

  ```
  $ sudo make install
  $ sudo make cups
  ```
- Open Printer Settings

  ```
  system-config-printer&
  ```

  or

  ```
  gnome-cups-manager&
  ```

  or if you like more the cups-browser, open this link: http://localhost:631/admin
- Select **Add** printer

  - Here selected a network printer
  - When asked to search for a driver (a bit fuzzy here), I selected **Konika-Minolta 1690F** and it found my OKI MC160n.
  - For the other configuration I used default values
- Print a test page
  Printed test page ---> Success!
  Select "OK" and done!

Comment: Hi Saabyurk, and welcome to askubuntu! What do you mean with **./getweb 1690....**?

Comment: I took a look at the tar. Why do you need to compile the printer? Wouldn't it be enough to copy the `KONICA_MINOLTA-magicolor_1690MF.ppd`  into the `/usr/share/cups/model` directory?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. I probably don't belong on this forum but I was so happy to get my OKI printer working on Linux after years of trying that I had to thank Squelsh for the tip. All I can say is that the ./getweb runs a script which is part of the tar package. It supposedly searches for extra features for the specified printer. As for your ppd question, I just don't know. I only followed the instructions at the link where I got the driver. At age 75, my enthusiasm for experimenting has waned greatly. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I see no driver on the manufacturer's site [after a quick search](http://www.oki.co.uk/support/printer/printer-drivers/results.aspx?prodid=tcm:122-3997-16&search=1&OSId=Linux&languageId=English&type=%7CDrivers).

Therefore, try the following:

- from the Dash Menu, launch the 'Printing' app
- click Add
- follow the instructions: either your printer and its specific driver will be listed, or you will be able to select "Generic printer driver", or at least the suggested driver if any.

If it works or if it does not, don't hesitate to tell us how it went !

Comment: I followed the instructions and couldnt  find it's specific driver. Then I selected "generic printer driver" and choose one of them but it didn't work. Should I try all the generic drivers and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

On http://forums.openprinting.org/read.php?33,11610 I found that the **OKI MC160n** actually is a **re-branded KONICA MINOLTA magicolor 1690MF**.
Therefore the KONICA MINOLTA magicolor 1690MF Foomatic/foo2lava cups driver works out of the box.
I had to use an adress scheme like this: `lpd://192.168.0.150/print`

Answer (score 0):

I have a C610 OKI which is a great printer. OKI told me that they have no drivers for Ubuntu. (I told them to tell their IT people to get on it!) Added the printer from the dash, and first loaded the best-fit OKI driver from the list. Not so good. Deleted the printer and started over using the generic recommended driver. Works much better. Only problem is that I get an error message a couple of minutes after the print job telling me that there is a timeout error, which I'll try to figure out. Otherwise great results.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  I just install driver OKI C110 from LinuxMint base driver pack and it work perfect for OKI MC160n.
Have Duplex and color.
Have a good day from Ukraine ;)
[image]

Becides if you have problem with printing two side - to fix it just create custom size A4 of OKI printer with OKI margins
Then problem is fixed
[image]